# iOS iPhone how to handle "User can use app from multiple devices" kind of requirement?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, cloud, synchronization

I'm building an enterprise app, and have a very long list of requirements in front of me.

One of them reads "The app needs to be usable on multiple devices by the same user, such as iPhone and iPad sync with cloud for seamless experience".

This seriously concerns me, as it may involve a huge level of complexity. The app uses a local core-data based stack to keep a local version of the data, and will need to back up this data to the cloud. From your experience, **is such core data to cloud sync feasible?** How much effort is involved in keeping multiple devices seamlessly synced to a cloud based storage?

Any other input on how to handle/talk about such requirement in an intelligent manner is appreciated! Are there any demos that may get me up to speed on such "multi-device" kind of app?

Comment: UIManagedDocuments will fast track you to iCloud and Core Data.  Shouldn't be too hard of a project, tons of people already do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's also some further reading on Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/iCloud/iCloud.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW1

Answer (score 0):

There is functionality to sync coredata with iCloud

Have a look at [iOS How-To : Using Core Data with iCloud](http://goddess-gate.com/dc2/index.php/post/452)